# Compile time checking in Design by Contract?

Tags: design-by-contract

I read that compiler can enforce dbc at compile time.. How does it do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the most powerful static DbC language so far is [Spec# by Microsoft Research](http://Research.Microsoft.Com/SpecSharp/). It uses a powerful static analysis tool called [Boogie](http://Research.Microsoft.Com/Boogie/) which in turn uses a powerful Theorem Prover / Constraint Solver called [Z3](http://Research.Microsoft.Com/projects/z3/) to prove either the fulfillment or violation of contracts at design time.

If the Theorem Prover can prove that a contract will *always* be violated, that's a compile error. If the Theorem Prover can prove that a contract will *never* be violated, that's an optimization: the contract checks are removed from the final DLL.

As Charlie Martin points out, proving contracts in general is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem and thus not possible. So, there will be a lot of cases, where the Theorem Prover can neither prove nor disprove the contract. In that case, a runtime check is emitted, just like in other, less powerful contract systems.

Please note that Spec# is no longer being developed. The contract engine has been extracted into a library, called [Code Contracts for .NET](http://Research.Microsoft.Com/Contracts/), which will be a part of .NET 4.0 / Visual Studio 2010. However, there will be no language support for contracts.

Comment: Thanks Jorg, very good reply. Do you know why it's not gonna be in C#, similar to Spec# style?

Comment: It will be included in .NET 4.0 in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53695440/is-it-possible-to-enforce-design-by-contract-checks-at-compile-time

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can use [static analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_code_analysis) to look at your program and determine whether it does the right thing. As a simple example, the following code might try to take the square root of a negative number (C++):

```
double x;
cin >> x;
cout << sqrt(x) << endl;
```

If the compiler knows that `sqrt` should never be called with a negative number, it could flag this as a problem because it knows that reading from user input *could* return a negative number. On the other hand, if you do this:

```
double x;
cin >> x;
if (x >= 0) {
    cout << sqrt(x) << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Can't take square root of negative number" << endl;
}
```

then the compiler can tell that this code won't ever call `sqrt` with a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

Design by Contract is a very abstract term, since there can be many specification formalisms with different powers of expression. In addition, there is at present a limit to the abilities of static analysis to check and enforce specifications. It's one of the most active academic and industrial research fields in computer science.

In practice, it is likely that you will use some subset of contracts and checking, and that depends on the language that you are using and on the plugins or programs you install.

In general, static analysis tries to build a model of the contract, and a model of the actual program, and compare them. For example, if the contract doesn't let you invoke a function when an object is in state S, it will try to determine whether in any invocation sequence you could end up in state S.

Answer (score 0):

Which compiler and what language?  Eiffel can do it to some extent.  But remember that completely enforcing design-by-contract would mean being able to solve the Halting Problem (proof: assume you have a compiler that could do it.  Then the compiler would have to be able to identify an arbitrary function with a true exit condition that can't achieve the exit condition because of an infinite loop or infinite recursion.  Thus it reduces to halting.)

What is usually meant by this is that if you have a call

```
  foo(a);
```

and somewhere else define

```
  function foo(a:int) is
     assert 0 < a && a < 128
     ...
  end
```

then the compiler can check that a is, in fact, going to be in the open interval (0..128).

Comment: so for instance I call foo() inside some other method like below:
function bar(b:int){ assert 0 < b && 0 >150;  foo(b); } would compile complain about it??

Comment: In Eiffel, I think so.  It would be very difficult for a C-like language to test that.

Answer (score 0):

Some languages like [D](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/) have reasonably powerful compile time constant folding and compile time condition checking (for D `static assert(boolCond, msg);`, IIRC C/C++ can use `#if` and `pragma` or `#error`)

Comment: D's static assert only work on values known at compile time.
C/C++ #if/#error only works at values known when the preprocessor is run.

Design by Contract typically verifies assumptions at runtime - but a sufficiently smart program can verify a large subset of them at compile time.

Comment: Allowing the compiler to dive into that range gets very complex very fast and makes it very hard for the programmer know what error it won't catch. Not a good thing in my book.